# How to load data asynchronously to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asynchronous

I am currently fetching links from a website as a google search engine.I have to fetch links with a single keyword in a textbox  with a single button click.i have  some methods to fetch data and these methods will be looped multiple times.So i have used asynchronous task to loop  these methods to multiple times  and its working fine.The problem i have with the asynchronous task is, while completion of first looping when i try to bind the fetched data to gridview in aspx page it's not binding.

```
  string[] cities = { "auburn", "bham", "dothan", "shoals", "huntsville", "mobile", "montgomery", "tuscaloosa" };
string[] states = { "montgomery", "delaware" };
string[] categories = { "sss", "ccc", "eee", "ggg", "hhh", "jjj", "ppp", "res", "bbb" };

protected async void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        dt.Columns.Add("Links");
        dt.Columns.Add("title");
        dt.Columns.Add("keyword");
        dt.Columns.Add("city");
        dt.Columns.Add("state");
        dt.Columns.Add("S.no");
        dt.Columns.Add("linkid");
        for (int s = 0; s < Statename.Count; s++)
        {


            //looping for state
            for (int i = 0; i < dscity.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //looping for categories
                for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++)
                {

                    for (int w = 0; w < word.Length; w++)
                    {

                        //looping for pages
                        for (int j = 0; j < pagecount; )
                        {
                            if (j == 0)
                            {

                                str = "http://" + dscity.Tables[0].Rows[i]["citycode"].ToString() + "website/search/?&areaID=&catAbb=" + categories[m] + "&query=" + word[w] + "&sort=rel";


                            }
                            else
                            {

                                str = "http://" + dscity.Tables[0].Rows[i]["citycode"].ToString() + "website/search/?s=" + j + "&areaID=&catAbb=" + categories[m] + "&query=" + word[w] + "&sort=rel";

                            }


                            // Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                            await TaskEx.Run(() => binddata(str, dscity.Tables[0].Rows[i]["citycode"].ToString(), categories[m], word[w], Statename[s]));

                            j = j + 100;
                            if ((pagecount % 100) != 0 || pagecount > 100)
                            {
                                pagecount = ((pagecount / 100) + 1) * 100;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }




}

public void binddata(string str, string city, string category, string keyword, string statename)
{
    try
    {

        string[] result;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string webhtml = client.DownloadString(str);

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(str);
        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string source = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] location = new string[] { "<span class=\"crumb\">" };
        location = source.Split(location, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string[] location1 = new string[] { "<a href=\"/\">", "</a> &gt;</span>" };
        location1 = location[2].Split(location1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string state = location1[0];

        string[] title1 = new string[] { "\">", "</a></span>" };
        title1 = location[3].Split(title1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string title = title1[1];



        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "<div class=\"content\">" };
        stringSeparators = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        //spliting for pagecount
        string[] resultcount = new string[] { "<span class=\"resultcount\">" };
        resultcount = stringSeparators[0].Split(resultcount, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (resultcount.Length > 1)
        {

            string[] resultcount1 = new string[] { "</span></span>" };
            resultcount = resultcount[1].Split(resultcount1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(resultcount[0]);

            if (stringSeparators[1].Contains("<div class=\"toc_legend bottom\">"))
            {
                result = new string[] { "<div class=\"toc_legend bottom\">" };
            }
            else
            {
                result = new string[] { "<div id=\"floater\">" };
            }


            stringSeparators = stringSeparators[1].Split(result, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string data = stringSeparators[0].Replace("<a class=\"gc\" href=", "");
            data = data.Replace("href=\"#\"", "");
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlSnippet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlSnippet.LoadHtml("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div><div>" + data + "</body></html>");
            List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();
            //bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

            ExtractAllAHrefTags(htmlSnippet, city, category, title, keyword, statename);

        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);

    }

}

private void ExtractAllAHrefTags(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlSnippet, string city, string category, string title, string keyword, string statename)
{
    //bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    try
    {
        string ssss = string.Empty;
        string temp = string.Empty;
        List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();
        DataRow dr1;
        var nodes1 = htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");

        foreach (HtmlNode link in nodes1)
        {

            if (link.OuterHtml.Contains("=\"row\""))
            {
                // HtmlAttribute att =
                //HtmlAttribute tag = link.ChildNodes[5].InnerHtml;
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlSnippet1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                htmlSnippet1.LoadHtml("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>  " + link.ChildNodes[5].InnerHtml + "</body></html>");
                foreach (HtmlNode link1 in htmlSnippet1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    string desc = link1.InnerHtml;
                    HtmlAttribute att = link1.Attributes["href"];
                    string temp2 = att.Value.ToString();

                    if (temp2.Contains(".html"))
                    {

                        if (desc != "" && temp2 != "")
                        {


                            if (temp2.StartsWith("/") && temp2.Contains(".html"))
                            {
                                ssss = "http://" + city + ".website.org/" + temp2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ssss = temp2;

                            }
                            dr1 = dt.NewRow();
                            dr1[0] = ssss;
                            dr1[1] = desc;
                            dr1[2] = keyword;
                            dr1[3] = city;
                            dr1[4] = statename;
                            dr1[5] = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
                            dr1[6] = "";
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);



                        }

                    }

                }


            }

        }


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

}

Comment: You can o it by using Jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593163/databind-grid-linq-asynchronous-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Are you sure that *all 114* lines of core are **meaningful** and must present in the question?

Comment: yes,i just provide an outline of the code